# Why can't binary insertion sort be O(n log n)?

Tags: insertion-sort

It seems to me that we are just missing the hardware necessary. Specifically, it is not unimaginable to design a list structure in memory, s.t when you write a value into element a, this leads some signal to change from 0 to 1, causing it to write the value previously at a to a + 1 (the output of a is automatically connected to the input of a + 1, you just need something to increment to trigger a write), and have this propogate down extremely fast (much faster than it takes to do other stuff), and thus have a roughly O(n log n) algorithm (of course, when you get to really large n, this propogation takes n time, so it really is an O(n^2) algorithm still, but it seems to me that for small n, this should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation is not about speed per se. Essentially, it captures the asymptotic behavior of a function. If that function describes the running time of an algorithm, Big-O notation describes its asymptotic order of growth.

> of course, when you get to really large n, this propogation takes n time, so it really is an O(n^2) algorithm

This doesn't make sense. The time complexity of insertion sort is not dependent on the input size; running time may differ, depending on the concrete input *values*, but insertion sort will still run Ө(n) or Ө(n²) for best or worst case, respectively.

Note that, if an algorithm runs in T(n) = n² + 2<sup>100</sup>, this is still O(n²). If an algorithm does stuff in O(n²) for you and computes the first billion digits of pi afterwards, it is still O(n²), provided that the computation afterwards is *independent of the input size n*.

Finally, quoting Introduction to Algorithms, 3<sup>rd</sup> by Cormen et al.:

> Before we can analyze an algorithm, we must have a model of the
>   implementation technology that we will use, including a model for
>   the resources of that technology and their costs.

Before you assess the running time of an algorithm, you need to agree on the general model of a computer you are going to use. So, hardware considerations are part of that agreement.